# Does an unused WMS layer slow down ArcMap project?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, wms, performance

Does an unused (not ticked) WMS layer which is in table of contents actually slow down an ArcMap project?

Comment: If not called, it shouldn't.  You can check if any request is made by using something like Fiddler

Comment: Have you tried timing the display speed of your MXD with and without your WMS displayed and present?